# Touch listener work in only last added view in android

Tags: android, view

I have added two `ZoomEditTextView` programmatically in `Relativelayout` and set `setOnTouchListener`. But `setOnTouchListener` works in only last added view.

Here is what I have tried:

```
ZoomEditTextView edittext = new ZoomEditTextView(Image_Process.this);
edittext.setLayoutParams(params);
edittext.setText("item,s");


rel_zoomable_et.addView(edittext);
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to rel_zoomable set on touch listener

Comment: Is it your full code?where is the second ZoomEdTtexView@frnd?

Comment: @CrazyAndroid - above code inside OnClick() so when i click button, every time ZoomEdTtexView will added in RelativeLayout